# Transponer en Python

Tags: python, dataframe

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
# Ejecución de una consulta con la informacion de las ventas
cur.execute("select numtienda, fechafin, desvest from tabla where numtienda = X and idarea = X and idcategoria = X order by numtienda, fechafin;")

# Asignamos la consulta al Dataframe
version = cur.fetchone()
df = pd.DataFrame(cur, columns=['numtienda', 'fechafin', 'desvest'])

# Cierre de la comunicación con PostgreSQL
cur.close()

#Convertir la venta y la fecha a un tipo valido
df["desvest"] = pd.to_numeric(df["desvest"], downcast="float")
df["fechafin"] = pd.to_datetime(df["fechafin"])
df["numtienda"] = pd.to_numeric(df["numtienda"], downcast="integer")
df.set_index('fechafin', 'numtienda', inplace=True)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el número de tienda se añada al desvest que le corresponde.

Saludos

Comment: Buen Dia. para mejorar tu pregunta y que sea mejor recibida, de ser posible que pongas el código de lo que estas realizando, como llenas Dataframe, y lo que haz intentado, y de preferencia algunos datos de ejemplo.

Comment: Bienvenido! aunque tu conoces tu problema, tienes que intentar transmitirselo a otros de la mejor manera posible, en concreto si pones el código y nos comentas los frameworks que estás usando, sería más fácil que te dieran ayuda. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas obtener más ayuda en tus preguntas :)

Comment: (1) ¿y qué si hay más de una tienda en el dataframe? (2) ¿qué tiene que ver esto con transponer?

Comment: @Pollo tal vez estoy queriendo trasponer cuando no es, lo que quiero es identificar por columna a cada tienda para poder mandar su información a un modelo SARIMA y que no intervengan las demás tiendas en su pronostico.

Comment: ¿No te sería más sencillo filtrar por el valor de la columna? `nuevo_df = df[df['numtienda']==232]`

Comment: @Pollo si, solo que soy algo nuevo en python, pero digamos que voy a estar ciclando entre una combinación de area/categoria los números de tienda seran variables, eso es lo que estoy trabajando, enviar cada una al modelo y guardar los resultados en un dataframe o añadirlos al final de la columna que le corresponde al desvest

Comment: Lo que estás queriendo hacer se llama *pivotear* (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) ... pero realmente no creo que sea la mejor opción para este caso, cuando podrías agrupar, o filtrar los valores... Aunque quizás convenga que expliques más a fondo el problema para no recomendarte que pivotees una columna cuando hay mejores soluciones